# Is it possible to position or float an element without affecting overflow?

Tags: css

I am working on a site design in which the main content area is centered via `margin: auto` and has a fixed width.

I would like to place another element slightly outside of this fixed width (off to the right, in my case) without affecting the overflow scrolling of the center content area.

Perhaps this is better explained with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rxje6/

In this example, try shrinking the bottom right pane and notice how the bottom scroll bar appears immediately after the orange goes out of view. Although this is the default behavior, **this is not what I want**. I prefer the scroll bar to only appear once the gray area is obscured and the orange to be hidden out of view.

I've tried absolute positioning, but the scroll bar still appears. Using `overflow: hidden` on the primary navigation div works, but simply chops off the overflowing orange.

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. Stackoverflow's tag helper seems to be down at the moment, so I'm placing this under **css** for now since I can't think of any others.

Comment: i have completely no idea what effect you would like to achieve. straightforward: where the orange box should be?

Comment: I am actually not looking to move the orange box... it is exactly where I want it to be (slightly off centered to the top right). I am simply trying to have it exist there without it affecting the browser's bottom scroll bar. Simply put, I do not want a scroll bar appearing when it's out of view. The scroll bar should only appear when my main content area is obscured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to wrap everything in a new `div`:

```
#container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: 400px
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/rxje6/1/

Comment: That is sheer brilliance, sir. Thank you! I will have to figure something out for my IE6 visitor's but that get's me 99% of the way there.

Comment: If the only problem is that `min-width` doesn't work, use this workaround: http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/